# How to find TableView section header Index Path?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to do some kind of action according to the TableView Section Header Index Path.
Is there any method to trace the section header Index Path?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? The header of a section does not have row but only a reference to a section.

Comment: can we detect its indexpath like we can detect indexpath of row?

Comment: @sandesh did you find a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

There is no existing method for that.

## Solution

Declare a section number variable in your custom header class.

```
class CustomHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
{

//
// MARK :- PROPERTIES
//

var sectionNumber: Int!

//
// MARK :- METHODS
//

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    // Initialization code ...
}

func configureWith(_ section: Int)
{
    self.sectionNumber = section
}

} // end of class
```

Then in your view controller inside `viewForHeaderInSection`, assign section value while instantiating your custom header.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "selectHeaderIdentifier") as! CustomHeader
    header.configureWith(section)
    return header
}
```

Now, you have in your custom header a section number property, use it as you want :]

```
header.sectionNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

how about *[func headerViewForSection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/headerViewForSection:)* ?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, headerViewForSection section: Int) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell")        

    // do some stuf, e.g.
    switch (section) {
    case 0:
        headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    default:
        headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    return headerCell
}
```